# RSpec Post and Namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I first used this RSpec test to post to my Env controller. After changing the namespace of my controller I can't seem to appropriately post to this controller. The namespace is 'api', and I've tried moving the RSpec file into an 'api' folder, tried changing the actual post parameters themselves, and added 'Api::' to the describe block. Any thoughts?

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Api::EnvsController do

    describe "POST create" do
        it "creates a new env" do
            expect { post :create, :env => {:name => "mym"} }.to change(Env,:count).by(1)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: just pass the proper controller name to the `describe` method

Comment: @apneadiving Still no dice. Perhaps it's something with my actual post method? Added the full class.